# Access Data Connectivity Issues

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, insert, record

I want to insert record in a table Book in a database Project.mdb successfully but while updating a record it says "No Record Found". Table in Access contains following fields PNR - FNAME - LNAME - SOURCE - DEST - DOJ - NOP
The code below does not show any error but it directly jumps to the last statement without updating or checking the values. Kindly help.

```
<%
Dim objConn
Dim objRS
Dim pnrNo
Dim varpnr
Dim varfname
Dim varlname
Dim vardoj
Dim varnop
Dim varsrc
Dim vardest
pnrNO = Request.Form("PNR")
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source="& _
            "D:\Project.mdb"
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
objRS.Open "Book", objConn
Dim flag
flag = 0
Do Until objRS.EOF
If objRS("PNR") = pnrNO Then
varpnr = objRS("PNR")
varfname = objRS("FNAME")
varlname = objRS("LNAME")
vardoj = objRS("DOJ")
varnop = objRS("NOP")
varsrc = objRS("SOURCE")
vardest = objRS("DESTINATION")
flag = 1
End if
objRS.MoveNext
Loop
objRS.Close
objConn.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing
%>
<% If flag = 1 Then %>
<html>
<body text="#FFFF00" bgcolor="#000000">

<p align="center"><font face="Cooper Black" size="6">MANAGE 

BOOKING</font></p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
    <CENTER>
    <form method="POST" action = "Update_Entry.asp">
        <table border="0" width="38%">
        <tr>
            <td width="202">PNR NUMBER</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="PNR" 

size="20" value = "<% =varpnr %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="202">FIRST NAME</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="FNAME" 

size="20" value = "<% =varfname %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="202">LAST NAME</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="LNAME" 

size="20" value = "<% =varlname %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="202">DATE OF JOURNEY</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="DOJ" size="20" 

value = "<% =vardoj %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="202">TOTAL PASSENGERS</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="NOP" size="20" 

value = "<% =varnop %>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="202">SOURCE</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="SOURCE" 

size="20" value = "<% =varsrc %>"></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
            <td width="202">DESTINATION</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="DESTINATION" 

size="20" value = "<% =vardest %>"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <p><input type="submit" value="UPDATE DETAILS"> 

</p>
        <p>&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="CLEAR"></p>
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>

</html>
<% 
else 
response.write("Record Not Found!!")
end if %>
```

Comment: Please add the tag for the language you are using.

Comment: I am using ASP code . I am a  student and this is a project work given to us. I wrote everything according to the notes but still this issue is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have there doesn't update the records, it just attempts to read them. However you will always have an empty recordset as the SQL statement to read the contents of the book table isn't valid. This needs to be along the lines of:

objRS.Open "select * from Book", objConn